# Installing Opencv Repository In Windows 10 for Python or Cmake

Tags: feature-extraction, feature-detection, language-features

I want to know if someone can help me with install opencv repository files in Windows 10 system.

I want to use xfeatures2d and i have been told from other peoples comments on other pages that the algorithm is patented and does not go with the open source softwares.

I want to do features detection and can achieve this using Python or Cmake as i have these two softwares to write C++ or Python code for it.

I have this error that xfeatures2d is not in the directory for Cmake and module has no object attribute xfeatures2d in Python.

I can program in C++ or Python so please, if you know either how to do that in a Python or Cmake, Please help.

My PC is Windows not Linux.

Answer (score 0):

That's because opencv doesn't include all the modules from now on. 
All the new modules are now developed separately, and published in the `opencv_contrib`.

You need to install `xfeatures2d` from https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib